# Jquery sortable dropped Z-index

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm having some problems with jquery UI sortable.

**Problem1**
Once an item is dropped into place and you want to redrag it, the draggable items goes behind other divs.

**Problem2**
I can't drag to original location, this can be related to problem1.

You can find my code on http://jsfiddle.net/dXzrV/

Thanks in advance!
Ward

Comment: You should pare down your example to use as little code as possible to illustrate your problem. I doubt anyone will wade through all that code to find what is probably a simple positioning conflict in your CSS.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. Are you viewing this in IE. I had similar problems with to Sortable function in IE. I believe setting the sortable and container divs to position:relative may fix it

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. It was with the position:relative on the .widget .widget-header